# refreshing current page when face box fades

Tags: php, ajax, facebox

I have a link that has a rel="facebox". When it is clicked it runs a php script from a separate file. I want to refresh the page automaticaly when the facebox fades. How can I do it? I've tried the headers and metas but it is not working.

Comment: " I want to refresh the page automaticaly when the facebox fades." ?

Comment: You will need to ensure that the Ajax call has completed so in the 'success' area check if the opacity of the facebox is zero and then do a window.location='my2ndpage.xxx;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind event afterClose.facebox:

```
$(document).bind('afterClose.facebox', function() {
    location.reload();
});
```